# For if loop in Java with array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Why does this code give me an error? I'm tyring to return the index of the first string in strArr that matches string s.

```
    private String strArr[];

public int indexOf(String s) {
        for(int i=0;i<strArr.length ;++i) {
            if (strArr[i].equals(s)){
             return i;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: you should say what your error is.

Comment: if you post a question asking why your code gives an error always post the error with it.

Comment: add a return outside if too. And its a compile time error

Comment: What do you expect to happen if the given string *doesn't* occur in the array?

Answer (score 4):

1. You are not initialising the array (therefore will get a NullPointerException when you try and get it's length)
2. You are not returning from the method if the string is not found

   ```
   public class StringArrayIndex {

   private String strArr[] = new String[]{"bar","foo", "cas"};

   public int indexOf(String s) {  
       for(int i=0;i<strArr.length ;++i) {
           if (strArr[i].equals(s)){
               return i;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println(new StringArrayIndex().indexOf("foo"));
   }
   }
   ```

When submitting to Stack Overflow you should try to give more information (full code samples, error messages etc) so people can help you more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also return some value e.g. -1 **after your loop**.

Your return is in an IF statement so the Java compiler is 
not sure you will ever enter this IF. And if you don't, you might
never return a value from your method. Therefore the compile-tome error.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything if you do not find the string in the array.

You should return something if the condition is never evaluated to true (outside your for loop for instance, you could return -1).

In your case, not all paths return a value.

Answer (score 0):

because if your method need to return something, it should return in all cases:

```
public int indexOf(String s) {
        for(int i=0;i<strArr.length ;++i) {
            if (strArr[i].equals(s)){
             return i;
            }
       }
     return -1; //if not find
}
```

it should return if your condition never get satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyIndexOf {
    private String strArr[] = {"x", "y", "z"};

    public int indexOf(String s) {  
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
            if (strArr[i].equals(s)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyIndexOf self = new MyIndexOf(); 
        System.out.println(self.indexOf("x"));
    }
}
```